# Decoding flags are not working correctly

Tags: c++, mfc, flags

I have designed some flags:

```
enum ImportAssignment
{
    OCLMChairman     = 0x00000001,
    OCLMOpenPrayer   = 0x00000002,
    OCLMClosePrayer  = 0x00000004,
    OCLMConductorCBS = 0x00000008,
    OCLMReaderCBS    = 0x00000016,
    PTChairman       = 0x00000032,
    PTHospitality    = 0x00000064,
    WTConductor      = 0x00000128,
    WTReader         = 0x00000256
};
```

In my dialog I read/write the flags from/to the registry:

```
void CImportOCLMAssignmentHistoryDlg::ReadSettings()
{
    m_dwImportFlags = theApp.GetNumberSetting(theApp.GetActiveScheduleSection(_T("Options")), _T("ImportFlags"), 0);
}


void CImportOCLMAssignmentHistoryDlg::SaveSettings()
{
    theApp.SetNumberSetting(theApp.GetActiveScheduleSection(_T("Options")), _T("ImportFlags"), m_dwImportFlags);
}
```

`SetNumberSetting` is basically a wrapper for `GetProfileInt` etc..

I then have two methods for encoding and decoding the flags into a series of BOOL variables (check boxes):

```
void CImportOCLMAssignmentHistoryDlg::DecodeImportFlags()
{
    m_bImportOCLMChairman = (m_dwImportFlags & ImportAssignment::OCLMChairman);
    m_bImportOCLMOpenPrayer = (m_dwImportFlags & ImportAssignment::OCLMOpenPrayer);
    m_bImportOCLMClosePrayer = (m_dwImportFlags & ImportAssignment::OCLMClosePrayer);
    m_bImportOCLMConductorCBS = (m_dwImportFlags & ImportAssignment::OCLMConductorCBS);
    m_bImportOCLMReaderCBS = (m_dwImportFlags & ImportAssignment::OCLMReaderCBS);
    m_bImportPTChairman = (m_dwImportFlags & ImportAssignment::PTChairman);
    m_bImportPTHospitality = (m_dwImportFlags & ImportAssignment::PTHospitality);
    m_bImportWTConductor = (m_dwImportFlags & ImportAssignment::WTConductor);
    m_bImportWTReader = (m_dwImportFlags & ImportAssignment::WTReader);
}


void CImportOCLMAssignmentHistoryDlg::EncodeImportFlags()
{
    m_dwImportFlags = 0; // Reset
    if (m_bImportOCLMChairman) m_dwImportFlags |= ImportAssignment::OCLMChairman;
    if (m_bImportOCLMOpenPrayer) m_dwImportFlags |= ImportAssignment::OCLMOpenPrayer;
    if (m_bImportOCLMClosePrayer) m_dwImportFlags |= ImportAssignment::OCLMClosePrayer;
    if (m_bImportOCLMConductorCBS) m_dwImportFlags |= ImportAssignment::OCLMConductorCBS;
    if (m_bImportOCLMReaderCBS) m_dwImportFlags |= ImportAssignment::OCLMReaderCBS;
    if (m_bImportPTChairman) m_dwImportFlags |= ImportAssignment::PTChairman;
    if (m_bImportPTHospitality) m_dwImportFlags |= ImportAssignment::PTHospitality;
    if (m_bImportWTConductor) m_dwImportFlags |= ImportAssignment::WTConductor;
    if (m_bImportWTReader) m_dwImportFlags |= ImportAssignment::WTReader;
}
```

When I first run the application the checkboxes are unticked. I then tick a couple. I close the dialog and re-open it. Always the first two are ticked.

I am supporting 64x and 32x builds.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `ImportAssignment` flags are wrong, starting with the first two-digit value. Those should be `0x10`, `0x20`, `0x40`, `0x80`, `0x100`. I always whip out Windows' *calc.exe* in *Programmer* mode to double check. Each value should have a single bit set, with all other bits cleared (`0x16` [i.e. 22 in decimal] is `10110` in binary, for example).

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the clarification. I updated my answer with how I now define the flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On further debugging I found the solution to my problem.

I had to adjust my **DecodeImportFlags** method:

```
void CImportOCLMAssignmentHistoryDlg::DecodeImportFlags()
{
    m_bImportOCLMChairman = (m_iImportFlags & ImportAssignment::OCLMChairman) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    m_bImportOCLMOpenPrayer = (m_iImportFlags & ImportAssignment::OCLMOpenPrayer) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    m_bImportOCLMClosePrayer = (m_iImportFlags & ImportAssignment::OCLMClosePrayer) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    m_bImportOCLMConductorCBS = (m_iImportFlags & ImportAssignment::OCLMConductorCBS) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    m_bImportOCLMReaderCBS = (m_iImportFlags & ImportAssignment::OCLMReaderCBS) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    m_bImportPTChairman = (m_iImportFlags & ImportAssignment::PTChairman) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    m_bImportPTHospitality = (m_iImportFlags & ImportAssignment::PTHospitality) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    m_bImportWTConductor = (m_iImportFlags & ImportAssignment::WTConductor) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    m_bImportWTReader = (m_iImportFlags & ImportAssignment::WTReader) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

It `m_iImportFlags & ImportAssignment::XXXXX` returns the actual flag value. So I needed conditional testing so that the `BOOL` could be set correctly.

Update: These are the ways I now declare the flags:

```
enum ImportAssignment
{
    /*
    OCLMChairman     = 1,
    OCLMOpenPrayer   = 2,
    OCLMClosePrayer  = 4,
    OCLMConductorCBS = 8,
    OCLMReaderCBS    = 16,
    PTChairman       = 32,
    PTHospitality    = 64,
    WTConductor      = 128,
    WTReader         = 256*/
    None             = 0,
    OCLMChairman     = 1 << 0,
    OCLMOpenPrayer   = 1 << 1,
    OCLMClosePrayer  = 1 << 2,
    OCLMConductorCBS = 1 << 3,
    OCLMReaderCBS    = 1 << 4,
    PTChairman       = 1 << 5,
    PTHospitality    = 1 << 6,
    WTConductor      = 1 << 7,
    WTReader         = 1 << 8
};
```